# Read all json data

Tags: c#, json, http-get

I've got problem with reading data. I can read only 10 of 100 items (rows), because it is paged. Does anybody know how can I read all items?

```
string res = getItems.getItemsApi();
ItemsPage ia = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemsPage>(res);

String Name;
String value = "";

for (int cou = 0; cou < ia.PageSize; cou++)
{
    ia.Rows[cou].GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(b =>
    {
        Name = b.Name.ToString();

        switch (Name)
        {
            case "1":
            case "ItemId":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].ItemId.ToString();

                break;
            case "2":
            case "Title":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].Title.ToString();
                break;
            case "3":
            case "Code":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].Code.ToString();
                break;
            case "4":
            case "UnitOfMeasurement":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].UnitOfMeasurement;
                break;
            case "5":
            case "ItemType":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].ItemType.ToString();
                break;
            case "6":
            case "VatRate":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].VatRate.Name;
                break;
            case "7":
            case "Price":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].Price.ToString();
                break;
            case "8":
            case "Currency":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].Currency.Name.ToString();
                break;
            case "9":
            case "RevenueAccountDomestic":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].RevenueAccountDomestic.ID.ToString();
                break;
            case "10":
            case "RevenueAccountOutsideEU":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].RevenueAccountOutsideEU.ID.ToString();
                break;
            case "11":
            case "RevenueAccountEU":
                value = ia.Rows[cou].RevenueAccountEU.ID.ToString();
                break;
            case "12":
            /*case "StocksAccount":
                Console.WriteLine(b + "     " + ia.Rows[cou].StocksAccount);
                value = ia.Rows[cou].StocksAccount.ToString();
                break;*/

            default:
                //Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection. Please select 1, 2, or 3.");
                break;
        }
```

---

```
public class VatRate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ResourceUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ResourceUrl { get; set; }
}

public class RevenueAccountDomestic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ResourceUrl { get; set; }
}

public class RevenueAccountOutsideEU
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ResourceUrl { get; set; }
}

public class RevenueAccountEU
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ResourceUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public VatRate VatRate { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public RevenueAccountDomestic RevenueAccountDomestic { get; set; }
    public RevenueAccountOutsideEU RevenueAccountOutsideEU { get; set; }
    public RevenueAccountEU RevenueAccountEU { get; set; }
    //public object StocksAccount { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsPage
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    public int TotalRows { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

if anyone know how to read all pages of data, please answer to me...

thx

```
    public static string getItemsApi()
    {
        bool apiMethodUrl = ConnectApi.GetApiResultContent(apiMethodUrlItems, Program.GetApiAccessToken(), out status, out result);

    return result;
    }
```

---

```
    public static HttpStatusCode GetApiSelectByIdStatusCode(string apiMethodUrl, string accessToken)
    {
        HttpStatusCode responseCode = HttpStatusCode.Unused;
        string resultContentStr;

        GetApiResultContent(apiMethodUrl, accessToken, out responseCode, out resultContentStr);

        return responseCode;
    }
```

Comment: where are you getting your data from?

Comment: i get data from web api

Comment: Does getItems.getItemsApi(); returns more then 100 items?

Comment: no It return 10 result..

Comment: anyone please help me

Comment: no idea? please i really need this...

Comment: It completely depends on the API.  If your API is paged, like you said, then presumably there is some parameter it accepts that allows you to select which page of results to return, or the size of the page (number of results per page) to return.  Also, presumably there is some way to find out how many pages of results there are.   But we have no way of knowing what parameters your API supports; you've given no details about that -- so you will need to ask the provider of the API.